# Writing different sinks with pyspark streaming is too slow (foreachbatch)

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm using pyspark in EMR (1 master r4.2xlarge and 6 nodes r4.2xlarge) to consume a kinesis stream (24 shards). The stream has information from different tables, because of that, I made a forEachBatch process that reads the data, made some parsing from data and put the final results in a different prefix on a s3 bucket. The problem is that my consume architecture is fetching the data every 5 minutes and only consume 10,000 tx (100 tx per second aprox). (I have to be able to consume at least 2.4m of transactions per hour). I have changed different configurations like spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1") but it has no impact on the performance.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,coalesce,lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,year,month,dayofmonth,coalesce,lit,from_json, hour


def func(batch_df, batch_id):
    batch_df.persist()
    df = batch_df.withColumn("data", col("data").cast("string"))
    tableSchema = StructType() \
            .add("data", StringType())\
            .add("metadata", StringType())

    prov = df.select("*",from_json("data",tableSchema).alias("data_parsed")).select("data_parsed.*")

    metaDataSchema = StructType() \
        .add("timestamp", StringType()) \
        .add("record-type", StringType()) \
        .add("operation", StringType()) \
        .add("partition-key-type", StringType()) \
        .add("schema-name", StringType()) \
        .add("table-name", StringType())\

    meta_prov = prov.select("*",from_json("metadata",metaDataSchema).alias("meta_parsed")).select("meta_parsed.*","data")
    meta_prov = meta_prov.withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "timestamp_stream")
    meta_prov = meta_prov.withColumnRenamed("operation", "operation_stream")
    filter_types_list =meta_prov.select('table-name').distinct().collect()

    for filter_type in filter_types_list:
        table = filter_type[0]
        final_df = None
        df_filtered = meta_prov.filter( (col("table-name") == table) )
        json_schema = spark.read.json(df_filtered.rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema
        final_df = df_filtered.withColumn('data', from_json(col('data'), json_schema)).select('data.*','record-type','operation_stream','timestamp_stream')
        string_df = final_df.select([col(c).cast("string") for c in final_df.columns])

        default_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        df_partitions = string_df.withColumn('datetime_col', coalesce(col("timestamp_stream"), lit(default_time))) \
            .withColumn("year", year(col("datetime_col"))) \
            .withColumn("month", month(col("datetime_col"))) \
            .withColumn("day", dayofmonth(col("datetime_col"))) \
            .withColumn("hour", hour(col("datetime_col"))) \
            .drop(col("datetime_col"))


        if not df_partitions.rdd.isEmpty():
            df_partitions.write\
            .mode("append").\
            format("parquet").\
            partitionBy("year", "month", "day","hour") \
            .save(f"s3a://mybucket/some_prefix/{table}/")
    batch_df.unpersist()




spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName(SPARK_APP_NAME) \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")

ks = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format('kinesis') \
        .option('streamName', stream_name) \
        .option('endpointUrl', endpoint_url)\
        .option('region', region_name) \
        .option("kinesis.client.avoidEmptyBatches", "true")\
        .option('startingPosition', 'TRIM_HORIZON')\
        .load()


ks\
    .writeStream\
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY)\
    .foreachBatch(func) \
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

Could you please help me with my streaming process?

Comment: why are you casting `data` column as string and then parse it using from_json? if the data is already struct column, you can still access the columns inside struct column.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).